# Doubt in evaluating a double integral $\iint _R (y-1)dA$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, greens-theorem

Using Green's Theorem, calculate
$$
I =\int_r \vec{F}(r) \cdot d\vec{r}
$$

$\vec{F}(x,y) := \langle y,xy \rangle$ and $C$ is a unit circle with center $(0,0),$ oriented counterclockwise.

Green's theorem is

$$
I =\int_r \vec{F}(r) \cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_R (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y})dA
$$

I have calculated $\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=y$ and $\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y}=1$.

I am having trouble with the bounds for the double integral. What should I use for them? Should I be converting this into polar coordinates?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. Did you try?

Comment: @ArcticChar yes, I did and I got r=[-1,1] and theta=[0, 2pi] with the integrand being r sin(theta) - 1. However, the answer I got was -4pi and when I calculated F(r)•dr i got -pi when they should equal each other.

Comment: The range for $r$ should be $[0,1]$

Comment: @ArcticChar Oh, thank you! But even when I do that i get -2pi when it should be -pi unless my integrand is incorrect.

Comment: Your integrand is correct. Very likely you did something wrong in the calculation.

Comment: @ArcticChar I thought so too but after putting it into an integral calculator, it also got the same thing. I am very confused haha.

Comment: Did you remember to add the extra factor of r from the $rdrd\theta$ conversion of $dxdy$?

Comment: @Alan ohhh! That was the issue thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply note that your integral is,

$\displaystyle I =\int_r \vec{F}(r) \cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_R (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}) \ dA = \iint_R (y-1) \ dA$.

$y$ is an odd function so its integral over the circle centered at origin will be zero (due to symmetry above and below x-axis). So using the fact that area of unit circle is $\pi$, your answer can  be simply written as,

$\displaystyle I = - \iint_R 1 \ dA = - \pi$